# How to add a custom delete option for backgrid rows

Tags: javascript, marionette, backgrid

i have developed editable grid using [backgrid](http://backgridjs.com/) and it looks good also. following is my output :

when i select the check box  and click on `delete`  icon, then the selected rows are deleted.

now i also would like to have the delete option on each row so that the user can delete the row directly.

How to put delete icon on each row.??

[image]

Comment: hey did u implemented multiple columns filter?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can make a custom cell.

```
var DeleteCell = Backgrid.Cell.extend({
    template: _.template(" PUT YOUR HTML BUTTON TEMPLATE HERE "),
    events: {
      "click": "deleteRow"
    },
    deleteRow: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.model.collection.remove(this.model);
    },
    render: function () {
      this.$el.html(this.template());
      this.delegateEvents();
      return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have a more complete example. I am totally new do backgrid and I have no idea what to do with this DeleteCell :-(

Comment: Hi @y-h-wong I'm still having difficulties. If you could really be bothered looking up my problet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612191/how-to-implement-delete-per-row-for-backgrid

Comment: Awesome, though simple enough, but this is the only place this answer exists.
+2 (if I could)